# PowerMock and Mockito is not working with JDK 17

Tags: mockito, junit4, powermock

I am using PowerMockito and Mockito for Junit(4) test class in JDK 17. But it is not working . Using following dependencies :

powermock version - 1.7.4 ,
Mockito - 1.10.19

It is throwing Initialization error in case of using Powermock. For mockito it is throwing these errors :

```
org.objenesis.ObjenesisException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryHelper.newConstructorForSerialization(SunReflectionFactoryHelper.java:54)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.<init>(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:41)
    at org.objenesis.strategy.StdInstantiatorStrategy.newInstantiatorOf(StdInstantiatorStrategy.java:68)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.getInstantiatorOf(ObjenesisBase.java:94)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.newInstance(WhiteboxImpl.java:259)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.newInstance(Whitebox.java:139)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.getPowerMockTestListenersLoadedByASpecificClassLoader(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:95)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:174)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:48)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:108)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:71)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:36)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
```

Can anyone suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The last release of powermock came in 2020, so not sure if it is actively being maintained. v1.7.x of powermock doesn't work with JDK 11+. Also, latest versions of mockito support mocking static methods, so there is no real value of using powermock anymore.

You should remove powermock dependency and upgrade to latest mockito 4.x that support mocking static classes/methods.

Though, in ideal world, you shouldn't need to mock static classes/methods though. If you have to, then its time to refactor the code.